# adding new strings to a hashmap java

Tags: java, hashmap, indexof

I am writing a program that reads log files and then counts the number of times that certain strings are displayed. I was trying to manually input the strings as keywords but since there are so many, I decided it would be better to search through the log files and when it encounters, "ua, " it should create a new string from "ua, " to the end of the line, add it to the hashmap, and increase the count for that particular string(all the strings I am interested in start with "ua, ").  I can't seem to figure out how to add the new strings into the hashmap. This is what I have so far.

```
public class Logs
{

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException 
{

 Map<String, Integer> dayCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (String str : KeyWords)
    {
        dayCount.put(str, 0);
    }

    File path = new File("C:\\P4logs"); 
    for(File f: path.listFiles())
    { // this loops through all the files + directories

        if(f.isFile()) 
        { // checks if it is a file, not a directory.

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f.getAbsolutePath())))
    {


String sCurrentLine;

while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) 
{
    boolean found = false;

    for (String str : DayCount.keySet()) 
    {
        if (sCurrentLine.indexOf(str) != -1)
        {
            DayCount.put(str, DayCount.get(str) + 1);
            found = true;
            break;
        }
     }
     if (!found && sCurrentLine.indexOf("ua, ") != -1)
     {
        System.out.println("Found an unknown user action: " + sCurrentLine);
        DayCount.put(key, value)    //not sure what to put here
     }
    }
   }
 for(String str : KeyWords)
    {
         System.out.println(str + " = " + DayCount.get(str));

    }

    }
   }
}
```

}

Comment: what do you mean you're not sure what to put there? ....just put there what you're putting elsewhere.

Comment: What is **DayCount**? How and where is it defined?

Comment: Is `DayCount` a standard `HashMap`?

Comment: DayCount is my hashmap defined as `Map<String, Integer> DayCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();`

Comment: @user200784: Use PascalCase for class names and camelCase for variables and methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to iterate over a hashmap's keys to see if one exists! That defeats the purpose of using a hashmap (lookup `O(1)` without collisions vs. `O(n)` in your solution). You should only have to do something like this:

```
//If a key doesn't exist in a hashmap, `get(T)` returns null
if(DayCount.get(str) == null) {
    //We know this key doesn't exist, so let's create a new entry with 1 as the count
    DayCount.put(str, 1);
} else {
    //We know this key exists, so let's get the old count, increment it, and then update
    //the value
    int count = DayCount.get(str);
    DayCount.put(str, count + 1);
}
```

On another note, consider following Java naming conventions. Variables should start with a lowercase letter (i.e., `dayCount` vs `DayCount`). Only classes should start with an uppercase letter. The way you have it right now, it looks like `DayCount` is a class with a static method called `put`.

Comment: @Vivian Paliath hmm okay but should str be defined as if im not looping it over anything?

Comment: @user2007843 I just used `str` as a placeholder. You will have to get the individual strings out of the line that you read from your file (basically split up `sCurrentLine`). I'm assuming that you're trying to count individual words or something like that.

Comment: @Vivian Paliath an example of what I am counting is `"ua, login, reboot"`.

Comment: @user2007843 Then you can just split `sCurrentLine` and examine the individual tokens to build up your map.

Comment: @Vivian Paliath so I added this but am having trouble with string types and what to iterate by. `for (String str : keyWords ) //this isnt working
              {
             
             str = sCurrentLine.split("-- ");
             
             if (str.contains("ua, "))
             {
                 //then do what you added`

Comment: What is `keyWords`? Is it a list of strings?

Comment: it was my list of strings I was counting, but now I guess I dont need that since I am going to be finding them in the log files on the fly

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26099/discussion-between-user2007843-and-vivin-paliath)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is your requirement -

```
it should create a new string from "ua, " to the end of the line
```

Since it's not clear if a line starts with "ua, " or "ua, " could be in the middle of the line. This is probably how it should look like -

```
  while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) 
    {

        if( sCurrentLine.indexOf("ua, ") != -1 ){
             String str = sCurrentLine.substr("ua, ");
             if(dayCount.get(str) != null){
                  dayCount.put(str, dayCount(str) +1 );
              }else{
                  dayCount.put(str, 1 ); 
              }
        }

    }
```